# when I cast value from first function and call it again i got syntax error

Tags: kotlin

```
    fun main() {

    val names = mutableListOf(1,2,"asdasd")
    val namee :Int = (names.first() as Int)?.plus(2)
    println(namee)
    println(names.first())

}
```

when I cast the returned value form first function and call first again in println get error syntax that the found type is any and required Int

Comment: It should be `Int?`, or you should call `!!.plus`.

Comment: Well that's strange, I'm on Kotlin 1.4.10 and this code snippet runs fine on it without any error